¿Como redireccionar en Django, de la página inicial a otra página en el mismo directorio templates?
Esto es el archivo views.py donde tengo declaradas dos vistas. La vista codigo es la vista principal y accesible por http://127.0.0.1:8000/datos/ sin problema para acceder. La otra vista es reporte.html y depende de como la ponga aparece como http://127.0.0.1:8000/reporte.html como http://127.0.0.1:8000/datos/reporte.html. En ambo casos me dice "Página no encontrada".
    def datos(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = DatosForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                fecha = form.cleaned_data['fechanac']
                nombre = form.cleaned_data['nombre']
                return redirect('reporte', fecha, nombre )
        else:
            form = DatosForm()

    return render(request,'datos.html',{'form': form})

    def reporte(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            reporte = DatosForm(request.POST)
            if reporte.is_valid():
                form = DatosForm()
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/Los datos son inválidos/")
        else:
            return HttpsResponseRedirect("/Gracias/")

        return render(request,'templates/reporte.html',{'form': form})

Este es el archivo urls.py
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    urlpatterns = [
        path('datos/', views.datos, name='datos'),
        path('reporte/', views.reporte, name='reporte'),
    ]

Y este es el archivo datos.html
    <h4>Por favor ingrese los siguientes datos</h4>

    <form action="/reporte.html" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

El html captura los datos y hace el submit pero siempre regresa "Página no encontrada"
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Hay varias cosas que corregir en tu codigo en cuanto tenga un rato te ayudo sin problema

En tu formulario HTML, estás apuntando a "/reporte.html" como la acción del formulario. Esto intentará enviar los datos a http://127.0.0.1:8000/reporte.html, que no existe según tus URLs definidas en urls.py.
<form action="reporte/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

